# Autowire a classpath directory / File to a Bean

Tags: java, spring, maven, autowired

I have a simple Spring bean

```
public class Widget {   
    public Widget(File rootDir) { ... }
}
```

and in my application context XML I want to create an instance of `Widget`:

```
<bean id="widget" class="com.example.Widget">
    <constructor-arg type="java.io.File" value="classpath:/someDir"/>
</bean>
```

When I run in from my IDE it works, the string is converted to a File and passed to the ctor.

When I run it with `mvn exec:java` the file cannot be found, I get all sorts of errors, but revolving around:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name widget defined in class path
>   resource [META-INF/context.xml]: Could not resolve matching
>   constructor (hint: specify index/type/nam e arguments for simple
>   parameters to avoid type ambiguities)

---

So, how to I pass a *classpath* File (actually, directory) to a bean constructor in Spring?
I need a **directory** becasue then I want to scan it / list all files inside it.

Comment: Short version: you can't use `File`  with resources inside jars.

Comment: @chrylis oh that's sad. How can I open get access (say, get a `Reader`) to **all** files in `/someClassPathDir` thats on the classpath?

Answer (score 0):

> So, how to I pass a classpath File (actually, directory) to a bean
>   constructor in Spring? I need a directory becasue then I want to scan
>   it / list all files inside it.

I don't know if that's possible but you can get all of the resources on the classpath that match  a pattern using Spring.  See [PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.5.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/support/PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.html).  See the docs on using [Ant-style wildcards](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#resources-app-ctx-ant-patterns-in-paths).

Try this for your constructor:

```
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
...
public Widget(Resource[] resources) { ... }
```

and in your XML, something like this (change the Ant pattern to match your use case):

```
<bean id="widget" class="com.example.Widget">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
              <value>classpath:/someDir/*.foo</value>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Before using this, I recommend you take a look at the caveats related to non-filesystem resources mentioned in the PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver Javadocs.